# How to send and receive a file in Xabber client

Tags: android, xmpp, ejabberd

I'm an Android developer.
I have a Ejabberd server for XMPP. I've compiled Xabber in Android Studio, and connected it to Ejabberd server and text chat with it.
How can I send a file from one Xabber client to another?
Do you have any file transferal part in Xabber?
How can I implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like file transfer hasn't been implemented in Xabber yet.  There are two feature requests for it in the issue tracker, [#23](https://github.com/redsolution/xabber-android/issues/23) and [#387](https://github.com/redsolution/xabber-android/issues/387).